# Delphi routine to read RSSI of a wireless connection?

Tags: delphi, logging, wireless, rssi

I want to write a simple utility to regularly log the RSSI of my WiFi router to a text file.  Does anybody know of a Delphi library or API wrappers to read the RSSI value of a wireless router?

Comment: You need [`WlanGetNetworkBssList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706735(v=vs.85).aspx) to have the `WLAN_BSS_ENTRY` ('lRssi'), in the `WLAN_BSS_LIST` for the BSS you're interested in. I think..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the RSSI of your active network wifi connection using the [Native Wifi API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), after of call the `WlanOpenHandle` and `WlanEnumInterfaces` functions you must execute the [`WlanQueryInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method passing the `wlan_intf_opcode_current_connection` enum value and a pointer to a [`WLAN_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, from here you must access the [`wlanAssociationAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) element and finally read the value of the `wlanSignalQuality` field.

This is the description of this field.

> wlanSignalQuality
>
> ```
> A percentage value that represents the signal quality of the network.
> ```
>
> WLAN_SIGNAL_QUALITY is of type ULONG. This member contains a
>   value between 0 and 100. A value of 0 implies an actual RSSI signal
>   strength of -100 dbm. A value of 100 implies an actual RSSI signal
>   strength of -50 dbm. You can calculate the RSSI signal strength value
>   for wlanSignalQuality values between 1 and 99 using linear
>   interpolation.

Try this sample code

```
uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  nduWlanAPI   in 'nduWlanAPI.pas',
  nduWlanTypes in 'nduWlanTypes.pas';

procedure Scan();
var
  hClient              : THandle;
  dwVersion            : DWORD;
  ResultInt            : DWORD;
  pInterface           : Pndu_WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST;
  i                    : Integer;
  pInterfaceGuid       : TGUID;
  pdwDataSize, RSSI    : DWORD;
  ppData               : pndu_WLAN_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTES;
begin
  ResultInt:=WlanOpenHandle(1, nil, @dwVersion, @hClient);
 try
  if  ResultInt<> ERROR_SUCCESS then
  begin
     WriteLn('Error Open CLient'+IntToStr(ResultInt));
     Exit;
  end;

  ResultInt:=WlanEnumInterfaces(hClient, nil, @pInterface);
  if  ResultInt<> ERROR_SUCCESS then
  begin
     WriteLn('Error Enum Interfaces '+IntToStr(ResultInt));
     exit;
  end;

  for i := 0 to pInterface^.dwNumberOfItems - 1 do
  begin
    Writeln('Interface  ' + pInterface^.InterfaceInfo[i].strInterfaceDescription);
    WriteLn('GUID       ' + GUIDToString(pInterface^.InterfaceInfo[i].InterfaceGuid));
    pInterfaceGuid:= pInterface^.InterfaceInfo[pInterface^.dwIndex].InterfaceGuid;

    ppData:=nil;
    pdwDataSize:=0;
    ResultInt:=WlanQueryInterface(hClient, @pInterfaceGuid, wlan_intf_opcode_current_connection, nil, @pdwDataSize, @ppData,nil);
    try
      if (ResultInt=ERROR_SUCCESS) and (pdwDataSize=SizeOf(Tndu_WLAN_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTES)) then
      begin
        Writeln(Format('Profile %s',[ppData^.strProfileName]));
        Writeln(Format('Mac Address %.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x',[
        ppData^.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Bssid[0],
        ppData^.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Bssid[1],
        ppData^.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Bssid[2],
        ppData^.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Bssid[3],
        ppData^.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Bssid[4],
        ppData^.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Bssid[5]]));
        RSSI := (ppData^.wlanAssociationAttributes.wlanSignalQuality div 2) - 100;
        Writeln(Format('RSSI %d dbm',[RSSI]));
      end;
    finally
      if ppData<>nil then
       WlanFreeMemory(ppData);
    end;
  end;
 finally
  WlanCloseHandle(hClient, nil);
 end;
end;

begin
  try
    Scan();
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

**Note** : unfortunately AFAIK doesn't exist a *official* translation of the Native Wifi API headers to Delphi, so in the meantime you can use [these](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12733424/Blog/WlanAPI.zip).

Comment: I'm wondering if there should be more to it then linear interpolation, as signal quality would at least have to account for noise. +1 anyway..

Comment: Thanks @RRUZ.  A perfect starting point for what I need.  I had to skip the `and (pdwDataSize=SizeOf(Tndu_WLAN_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTES))` test as I could not get `pdwDataSize` (604) and `SizeOf(Tndu_WLAN_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTES)` (600) to agree with XE1. No doubt something to do with alignments.